# Подкрасить строки на основании списка слов в другом листе

Tags: excel

Как сослаться на список слов, скажем на другом листе поля ?

Книга с примером https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgfvDQ65okq0_HmiQeXroJsJsMTA?e=dIal9u , на Листе2 тот самый список слов который нужно использовать.

[image: Лист1]

Список слов на Листе2

[image: Лист2 (на этот список слов нужно сослаться)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выделить данные, начиная с первой строки (или выделить столбцы с данными).

Закладка *Главная-Условное форматирование-Создать правило-Использовать формулу*:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Лист2!$A:$A;$B1)
```

Если нужно закрасить значения, которые содержат в себе значения из списка (например: *яблоки55*), то немного сложнее:

```
=ИЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСКПОЗ(Лист2!$A$1:$A$2&"*";$B1;)))

=СЧЁТ(ПОИСКПОЗ(Лист2!$A$1:$A$2&"*";$B1;))
```

Для двух последних формул в диапазоне списка не должно быть пустых ячеек. Или усложнять формулы проверкой этого диапазона:

```
=СЧЁТ(ЕСЛИ(Лист2!$A$1:$A$99<>"";ПОИСКПОЗ(Лист2!$A$1:$A$99&"*";$B1;)))
```

Comment: блин, гениально. работает.

Comment: Гениальности - 0. Достаточно иметь небольшой опыт применения функций.

Comment: скажите, а если слово слитно в строке например яблки165? звездочка не помогает..

Comment: не работает почему то.. =СЧЁТЕСЛИ(ПОИСК(Лист2!$A:$A;B1))

Comment: Потому что *СЧЕТЕСЛИ* принимает диапазон листа, Вы же пытаетесь скормить ей результат вычислений.  Добавил формулу в ответ

Comment: то есть, я просто хотел в строке "543яблоки165" найти слово "яблоки". речь идет об одной и той же ячейке, в которой эта строка. почему вдруг $A:$A изменилось на $A$1:$A$2 (меня наверное не правильно поняли.). -Про счётесли понял (моя глупость). -Пустых ячеек не предусматривается в списке слов на втором лисет.

Comment: Я понял, нужно было изменить сам принцип поиска. Формула =СЧЁТ(ПОИСКПОЗ(Лист2!$A$1:$A$2&"*";B1;)) работает. Но подкрашивается не вся строка, а только первый столбец.

Comment: Закрепил столбец в ссылке. === *почему вдруг $A:$A изменилось на $A$1:$A$2* - потому что пустых ячеек в диапазоне быть не должно. А для *СЧЕТЕСЛИ* целый столбец указывать можно, функция понимает, где данные заканчиваются, и лишнего не считает.

Comment: Спасибо. Первоначально ответ уже был дан, мне не следовало дополнять условиями, или надо было как новую тему :)